# Disable AR viewing for Google model-viewer

Tags: 3d, web-deployment, augmented-reality, gltf, model-viewer

I try to render a 3D model into a website but using Google model-viewer, however I only have high-poly glb format, which is not compatible to Iphones. Can I disable AR viewing for the model, so the visitors can only see the model in web browser, and will not be able to activate the AR view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily possible by removing the `ar` attribute from the component. You did not post your code, but I suspect it is set currently.

This is documented [here](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#augmentedreality-attributes).

You can also only allow AR for android, by setting only some `ar-modes`.
This should allow all modes except for `quick-look` on iOS, thus ommiting the unsupported platform:

```html
<model-viewer src="mymodel.glb" ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer" ar-scale="auto" camera-controls alt="..." skybox-image="myskybox.hdr"></model-viewer>
```

By the way: You can also convert your `.glb` file to `.usd` with [this](https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf) tool or directly [online](https://spase.io/playground).